# Using dictionary-style data-types in Swagger

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, swagger-2.0

Imagine that I have a WebAPI action defined as follows:

```
[HttpGet]
public string GetFirstValue(KeyValuePair<string, string>[] data)
{
    data = data ?? new KeyValuePair<string, string>[0];

    return data.Any() ? data.ElementAt(0).Value : "No items supplied";
}
```

I have a model-binder to convert each query-string parameter into an array entry.

You would call it like:

```
http://localhost/MyController/GetFirstValue?Fruit1=Apple&Fruit2=Banana
```

The model-binder converts this into an array like `[{Fruit1=Apple},{Fruit2=Banana}]`, and the action returns `Apple` (as that is the first entry).

I want to document this using Swagger, but the default implementation of Swagger UI will end up generating a URL that puts all the data into multiple query-string parameters called `data`, which is not how I want to expose my API.

```
http://localhost:9102/MyController/GetFirstValue?data=Fruit1%3DBanana&data=Fruit2%3DApple
```

Any ideas? I'm happy to use a different data-type in my action parameter, such as a `Dictionary<string, string>`, or an IEnumerable or similar - as long as it's an extensible mechanism for providing arbitrary key/values.

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing isn't possible in Swagger. Referring to the [Swagger spec](http://swagger.io/specification/), you need to specify a list of parameters for an operation and each parameter requires a fixed name. There isn't a way to say in Swagger "This operation accepts an arbitrary number of query string parameters with unspecified names".

If you removed the constraint about accepting arbitrary keys then it would be easy, you would just have a "Fruit" parameter of type Array[string] and expect your clients to call
http://localhost/MyController/GetFirstValue?Fruit=Apple&Fruit=Banana
etc. (Similar to the http://petstore.swagger.io/#!/pet/findPetsByStatus operation for example).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. We do need the arbitrary parameters thing though - in our case, it's for specifying a list of filters, where the data keys you are filtering on get defined at runtime. Que sera.

Comment: Hmm, bit clunky but how about having a "keys" parameter and a "values" parameter, both of type Array[string]? Then people could call http://localhost/MyController/GetFirstValue?key=fruit1&value=apple&key=fruit2&value=banana

Comment: Yeah, I could also have "?filter=key1%3Dvalue1&filter=key23Dvalue2", but both of those seem really clunky when query strings are already KV pairs!